# how to make a round ruler\scale in a circle using CSS3

Tags: css, animation, scale, geometry

i have made a circle using this code of css3

```
.circle{
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: red;
        border-radius: 100%;
    }
```

now in inside this circle i want to show a round scale\ruler (just like a dial \meter)
it possible to make a round ruler\scale in a cricle?

Comment: How many points/markings do you need inside the circle?

Comment: a scale contain like this ||||5||||10||||15|||....100 at least

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/jamessynge/QQ43x/embedded/result/